# XMLRPC Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Read timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: php, zend-framework, httpwebrequest, xml-rpc, config

I've Googled everywhere but no one has posted a solution, they all say to set the timeout in the config but how do you do this?

How do I reset/override this setting from my XMLRPC client or server?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
$server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://127.0.0.1/xmlrpc');
$client = $server->getProxy(); 

// Increasing the timeout
$client->setConfig(array('timeout'=>30));
```

Here is the error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_XmlRpc_Client_FaultException' 
with message 'Method "setConfig" does not exist' 
in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php:370
```

Trying to pass as arg:

```
$server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://127.0.0.1/xmlrpc', array('timeout'=>30));
```

Here is the error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to 
Zend_XmlRpc_Client::__construct() must be an 
instance of Zend_Http_Client
```

Found the solution and here it is:

```
$server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://127.0.0.1/xmlrpc');

// Get the HTTP Client used by the XMLRPC client
$http_client = $server->getHttpClient();

// Increasing the HTTP timeout
$http_client->setConfig(array('timeout'=>30));

$client = $server->getProxy();
```

One Line works for me as well:

```
$server = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://127.0.0.1/xmlrpc');

// Get the HTTP Client used by the XMLRPC client and increasing the HTTP timeout
$server->getHttpClient()->setConfig(array('timeout'=>30));

$client = $server->getProxy();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Zend documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.http.client.html) specifies the configuration parameters that you are allowed to use.  I would guess that you can simply increase the timeout from 10 seconds to 20 or 30.  Whatever is appropriate for you.

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client('http://example.org', array('timeout' => 30));
```

or:

```
$client->setConfig(array('timeout'=>30));
```

UPDATE - Zend_Http_Client is used by Zend_XmlRpc_Client. You can set and access the Zend_Http_Client via the Zend_XmlRpc_Client object.

```
$xmlrpc_client = new Zend_XmlRpc_Client('http://127.0.0.1/xmlrpc');
$xmlrpc_client->getHttpClient()->setConfig(array('timeout'=>30'));
```

I haven't tested this so I don't know that it will work but you can also pass in your own Zend_Http_Client object to a Zend_XmlRpc_Client object using the setHttpClient() method as described (rather arcanely) at the bottom of the Zend [documentation page for Zend_XmlRpc_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.client.html).

Comment: Hmm think I jumped the gun. Updated question

Comment: Looking for XMLRPC client not the HTTP client

Comment: Updating my answer - think this will solve your problem - 1 minute, please

Comment: thanks but I figured it out, thanks for leading me to find the solution

Answer (score 1):

Whatever client you're using:

```
$client->getHttpClient()->setConfig(array('timeout'=>30));
```

where `$client` could be a Rest or Soap Client.

Also, one of the answers here has a minor error that causes pain:

```
client->getHttpClient()->setConfig(array('timeout'=>30')); - remove single quote after 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Those answers are alright, though since Zend HTTP 2.0 *(released in 2012 - [see diff](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-http/commit/4d8fe645793e0f0354c3141b34562a7e83cb7a89))* it is :

`$client->getHttpClient()->setOptions(array('timeout'=>30));`