# XMLRPC calling SOAP need to return response instead of crashing/dying

Tags: php, soap, exception, try-catch, xml-rpc

So I have a XMLRPC developed in Zend PHP which calls a SOAP request to start another process (SOAP is not my script but the XMLRPC is).

During the SOAP request if the host is not found, this **sometimes** crashes my XMLRPC call.
How can I return the XMLRPC request with a response instead of an error? Does the logic look ok? I know all the functionality works and I have gotten the response I desire (sometimes) but I need to make sure the script doesn't crash. Any thoughts? tips?

Here is what I have

```
try {
   $soap_call = new ReportSoapClient();
   $soap_call->RunReport();
} catch(Exception $e) {
   // Set the Error Alert Email Message
   $this->setErrorAlertMessage($this->getErrorAlertMessage()."ERROR: SOAP Exception: ".$e->getMessage());
   // Send the Email
   $this->sendErrorAlertEmail();

   // This set the XMLRPC Response 
   $this->setXMLRPCResponse('Code: '.$e->getCode().' Message: '.$e->getMessage());
   // This is a logger
   $this->debug('Code: '.$e->getCode().' Message: '.$e->getMessage());
   // Return the XMLRPC Response
   return $this->getXMLRPCResponse();
}
```

Here is the email I get:

```
ERROR: SOAP Exception: Could not connect to host
```

Here is the error I get when crashing (happens only sometimes, why???):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Read timed out after 10 seconds' in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php:512
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php(330): Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->_checkSocketReadTimeout()
#1 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Http/Client.php(989): Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->read()
#2 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php(280): Zend_Http_Client->request('POST')
#3 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php(361): Zend_XmlRpc_Client->doRequest(Object(Zend_XmlRpc_Request))
#4 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/XmlRpc/Client/ServerProxy.php(93): Zend_XmlRpc_Client->call('system.multical...', Array)
#5 [internal function]: Zend_XmlRpc_Client_ServerProxy->__call('multicall', Array)
#6 /path/to/xmlrpc.client.php(70): Zend_XmlRpc_Client_ServerProxy->multicall(Array)
#7 {main}
  thrown in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php on line 512
```

I [increased the timeout to 30 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563680/xmlrpc-zend-http-client-adapter-exception-with-message-read-timed-out-after-10) (<-- Link: if you need to see how) and then I sometimes get this: (again why???):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Exception' with message 'Read timed out after 30 seconds' in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php:512
Stack trace:
#0 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php(330): Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->_checkSocketReadTimeout()
#1 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Http/Client.php(989): Zend_Http_Client_Adapter_Socket->read()
#2 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php(280): Zend_Http_Client->request('POST')
#3 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/XmlRpc/Client.php(361): Zend_XmlRpc_Client->doRequest(Object(Zend_XmlRpc_Request))
#4 /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/XmlRpc/Client/ServerProxy.php(93): Zend_XmlRpc_Client->call('system.multical...', Array)
#5 [internal function]: Zend_XmlRpc_Client_ServerProxy->__call('multicall', Array)
#6 /path/to/xmlrpc.client.php(23): Zend_XmlRpc_Client_ServerProxy->multicall(Array)
#7  in /usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/Http/Client/Adapter/Socket.php on line 512
```

Here is what comes back sometimes (this is the desired response):

```
Code: 0 Message: Could not connect to host
```

Comment: Did you know that XMLRPC and SOAP are different protocols?

Comment: yes I know, I just wanted to know why sometimes I get the error message: Could not connect to host and other times I get the error Fatal error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was the SOAP process erroring out and wasn't throwing the error properly. ugh